# Does a low rep user see a question has answers, if the answer is voted -3 or lower?

Tags: support, reputation, design, answers

I can't think of a way to test this for myself.
As I'm high enough rep to be able to see what is actually a spam answer that just hasn't had enough flags yet, I can also see on the main page that this question has an answer.

#### Header page

[image]

#### Q&A body

[image]

I've shrunk these right down as there's no need to be able to read them, only see that the header shows one answer, and the answer in the body is greyed out.

Would the header show one answer if I was new to that stack, low rep, or would it show 0?

Comment: You needn't compress the image manually, just suffix `m` or `s` to the end of url. Example: `https://i.imgur.stack.com/83hbF` becomes `https://i.imgur.stack.com/83hbFm` (apparently glorfindel did it in their answer)

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein But someone could copy the link from the edit page and paste the URL..

Comment: @ppwater The edit page contains the compressed image and not the original one. (i.e. the uploaded image is compressed)

Comment: @QueenieGoldstein - I'm aware of that, but as the answer in this case is spam, I specifically wanted it too small to be legible. Providing the full sized image on click-through would have defeated that object, hence I shrunk it before upload.

Comment: The obfuscation isn't really necessary IMHO, and it's still possible to find out what question it is: its ID ends with a 7. And it's a nonsense answer, but not really spam; it doesn't seem to promote anything. (But it might be that they botched the YouTube URL.)

Comment: Being able to read, or find, the particular question or answer simply wasn't relevant to this question. I really don't see why it's attracted more interest than the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Header (list) page shows the same value for everybody; all content of the list pages is cached and therefore looks the same, regardless of who is looking.

The number of answers on the Q&A page is calculated on the fly. If you have enough reputation to see deleted answers, those will be counted as well. The [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) currently has 128 answers according to the homepage, but when I open it it tells me it has 208 answers.

[image]

I'm sure it shows 128 for you. Now, answers with a score of -3 or lower are still not deleted, so low reputation users can see them as well, and they will see '1 Answer' on the Q&A page.

Comment: Ah, OK. I was thinking that -3 wouldn't show to new users. I'd forgotten the distinction applies to deleted, not downvoted. That's clear now.